# How do I convert a given number into time format HH:MM:SS in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I received a list of numbers in Custom format (Type: 000000) that represent military time.  It always contain 6 digits, and leading zeros are used when necessary.  For example:

- 123456 becomes 12:34:56 (pm)
- 000321 becomes 00:03:21 (am)
- 142321 becomes 14:23:21 (pm)

How do I convert the integers in Column A into the format in the Column B (hh:mm:ss)?  I'd like to use military, 24-hr clock.

Comment: How did you "receive them as integers"? `000321` is not an integer, so you must have gotten them in another format. (Knowing that format might make writing an answer easier.)

Comment: You're right...the format is Custom, type: 000000

Comment: You have this question tagged 'vba', but are you really trying to do this in VBA code? Or do you just want a formula you can use in an Excel cell?

Comment: I want to do this in VBA code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assuming its a real integer,and not text:

`=TIME(INT(A1/10000),INT(MOD(A1,10000)/100),MOD(A1,100))`

if it is text, then use

`=TIME(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2)),VALUE(MID(A1,3,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)))`

format the result however you want.

As a VBA Function: Integer:

```
Function RetTime(IntTime As Long) As Date
RetTime = TimeSerial(Int(IntTime / 10000), Int((IntTime Mod 10000) / 100), (IntTime Mod 100))
End Function
```

String:

```
Function RetTimeS(StrTime As String) As Date
RetTimeS = TimeSerial(Val(Left(StrTime, 2)), Val(Mid(StrTime, 3, 2)), Val(Right(StrTime, 2)))
End Function
```

Comment: in Excel's VBA Editor I tried using your formula but got the error "Sub or Fucntion not defined".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's a formula - no VBA needed

Comment: I understand, but I'm trying to do this in VBA (and not use the formula).  That is why I tagged VBA.  I tried to adapt your formula into VBA but am having no luck.

Comment: I've added the VBA equivalent - the function returns the time to the calling sub/function - use whichever corresponds to the format your data is in

Answer (score 6):

Try TEXT function, i.e. in B1

`=TEXT(A1,"00\:00\:00")+0`

and format as hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell if you want VBA code, or a formula for a cell, or what `Custom, type 00000` is. Sean's answer above is probably the best from the standpoint of using VBA functions properly, but I don't believe there's any way to format a time object in military time with "(am)" and "(pm)" tacked on to the end. At least not using standard Excel formatting. (Probably because am and pm are redundant in military time.)

So assuming your source data are really strings, here's an alternative, in case you really want 'am' and 'pm' for some reason:

```
=MID(A1,1,2) & ":" & MID(A1,3,2) & ":" & MID(A1,5,2) & IF(VALUE(MID(A1,1,2)) < 12," (am)", " (pm)")
```

Comment: sorry Alan, I put am and pm in parentheses to show what part of the day it was...but I don't want am or pm in my results..just numbers and colons