# Problems assigning a "time" function to a Name

Tags: vba, excel, time

How can I assign the following formula to a name value in Excel VBA:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
Name:="extraHours_" & dayNumber, _
    RefersTo:="=TIME(INT('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & "/10000);" & _
                "INT(MOD('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & ";10000)/100);" & _
                "MOD('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & ";100))"
```

Whenever I execute the script, it throws a "Runtime error", saying "error in formula". However, if I copy and paste the formula string to a cell in an Excel sheet, it evaluates correctly. The interesting thing is, if I remove the "TIME" function from the formula (which makes the formula rather senseless) it works fine.

I found the formula here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088253. The problem with the VBA code there is, that I must calculate the TIME "on-the-fly", means the value in `'Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow` may change.

Comment: `'Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow` should be the address of that cell. Are you sure `pasteRow` contains a valid row number?

Comment: Just tested it. It works fine... as long as the value of `pasteRow` is sensible! So if `pasteRow = 0` then you get the error, of course, because there is no cell B0. So what is it?

Comment: Also are you sure your local settings uses ";" instead of ","?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons for the error that i can immediately think of...

1. `pasteRow` is not a valid row number and hence it refers to a **non existent** / **invalid** cell address.
2. Your local setting do not use `;` as a separator. Try and replace `;` with `,`

The below two example works on separate settings

**Example 1** With `,` as the separator

```
pasteRow = 1
dayNumber = 1

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
Name:="extraHours_" & dayNumber, _
RefersTo:="=TIME(INT('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & "/10000)," & _
            "INT(MOD('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & ",10000)/100)," & _
            "MOD('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & ",100))"
```

**Example 2** With `;` as the separator

```
pasteRow = 1
dayNumber = 1

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
Name:="extraHours_" & dayNumber, _
RefersTo:="=TIME(INT('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & "/10000);" & _
            "INT(MOD('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & ";10000)/100);" & _
            "MOD('Tab1'!$B$" & pasteRow & ";100))"
```

Comment: hello! thank you very much for your help, now I can assign the formular to the name value, however it does not work though. i want to add to the "extraHours_" name a default time, e.g. 18:00pm which is 0,75 in excel timevalue. therefore I assign in excel (not vba) a formular to a cell "=time18 + extraHours_1". this gives me an error #NAME. if i step through the formular, the time18 value is resolved as 0,75. then, the extraHours_1 is resolved to the text string. then, excel wants to resolve TIME and there TIME is resolved to #NAME. but, whats wrong with the formluar?? i have no clue

Comment: I think, the TIME function respectively the TIMEVALUE function is the problem. I don't know why, but it seems, from this functions the problem originates. maybe the solution would be to use alternative functions instead of TIME etc. are there some?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm happy that I solved my problem, it makes me sad at the same time.

As you might guess from my bad english, I'm not using the "English" version of Excel (in fact, it is the German version). Thus, VBA must insert the Englisch "translation" of the formular. Then it works fine. This site may be helpful: http://de.excel-translator.de/

What confuses me is, if I copy and paste the concatenated VBA formular into a excel Cell it evaluates correctly, also I can record a formular with the macro recorder and use it in my VBA. However a selfconstructed VBA formular in german is not allowed.

Have a nice weekend!