# Excel: Convert number to time

Tags: excel, time, numbers

How do I convert the numbers to time like the following?: (using Excel formula)

```
120600 -> 12:06  
80100 -> 8:01  
2400 -> 00:24  
600 -> 00:06
```

I've only seen decimal values being converted to time but nothing like this.

EDIT:
I would like them to be in time format (24-hour clock format) so I can do some comparisons with them.

Comment: Do you need to perform calculations with these times? Or are you just looking for the visual?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to mention this. I edited my post.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087787/how-do-i-convert-a-given-number-into-time-format-hhmmss-in-vba

Comment: @Jackson This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a given number into time format HH:MM:SS in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087787/how-do-i-convert-a-given-number-into-time-format-hhmmss-in-vba)